# Run swift file in background of the app

Tags: ios, notifications, swift3

I made an app, which is searching for beacons when you open it. I want to continue searching when the app is in the background. For this und want continue running my viewcontroller.swift.
Especially send notifications when beacon is in region.

How can I do it?
I tried some stuff I found on the internet, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

See [Region Monitoring and iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) in the Location and Maps Programming Guide.

It doesn't work quite the way you're imagining, however. Your code won't run "in the background" in general. The system will monitor for the iBeacon and launch your app when it appears.

The short version is you create a `CLBeaconRegion` and then call `locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion` to watch for it.

Comment: I did it an it works. It still sends notifications, but only when the app is running. Do I have to put something in "func applicationDidEnterBackground"?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1. You'll need the `location` background mode. (Actually… I can't remember if that's true in this specific use case.)

Comment: The more important piece is to remember that you will be *launched*. So you're going to get a call to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` in the options.